# Displaying Microsoft Office docs in ios view

Tags: ios, ms-office, google-docs, qlpreviewcontroller

I've been trying to use the `QLPreviewController` but it's a little inflexible. It comes with a few extra buttons and some printing option. It's also not modifiable `ios6+`.

I'm trying to understand whether it's feasible to write my own previewer and if so, if anybody has any insights on how this can be done in an `iOS view`.

All I want is the ability to show a `Microsoft word / excel / ppt, pdf,` or maybe even a `Google doc` in an `ios view`.

Comment: load them into a `UIWebView` instance. it may help.

Answer (score 0):

You can actually display those bits in a `UIWebView`

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:fileName ofType:extension];

NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];

[self.webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url]];
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: The question states "All I want is the ability to show a Microsoft word / excel / ppt, pdf, or maybe even a Google doc in an ios view". You can do that in a UIWebView. It will also allow you to do whatever else a normal view allows you to do such as overlay views, buttons etc. if you need. That was my interpretation of the needs.

Comment: If you included an example of how to do such a thing, it would be an answer. As it stands, at < 10 words, it is a comment.

Comment: Well, I thought it would be quite clear once you just check the docs on UIWebView... Have updated the 7 month late answer, anyway.

Comment: Even if you had linked to the docs, link only answers are still not considered to be answered.